# Save raw http request data

Tags: http, server, request

What would be the fastest and least expensive way to save raw HTTP request data?

I want to set up an endpoint, for example https://www.example.com/h.gif and save/log the raw request data from all requests made to it.

Saving/logging could be to a text file or directly into a database.

All the endpoint should do is save the raw request data and return a valid response in the fastest possible time.

I would then parse and extract data from the saved requests in a separate process so as to not slow the response time of the original HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

[Amazon CloudFront access logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html) might be a viable solution. It doesn't log the entire raw request data but I looks like everything I need is logged. The only additional charge is the cost of storing the log file in Amazon S3.

One downside is that logs are saved incrementally reather than istantly.